# Why does this looping process take so long?

Tags: java, performance, loops, arraylist

I am writing Java code, to apply a filter to an image (made up of an array (300 x 300 values) ). I am taking in a number of neighbouring values from the array, averaging them and adding them to an ArrayList, to generate the new values, and ultimately a filtered image. I appreciate that the ArrayList is huge (87616 objects), but I don't know how to break the process down more.

As you can see I am new to this. All help gratefully received!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Analyst {


    /**
    * Creates a storage object of class Storage within which array data is held
    */
    public Analyst () {
        Storage store;
        store = new Storage();

        //Create new DataReader class, in which original data can be read from, initialise it with object file
        DataReader file = new DataReader();

        //Create neighbours ArrayList to hold neighbour objects within Moore radius
        ArrayList<Double> neighbours = new ArrayList<Double>();

        //Create newValues ArrayList to hold mean value calculated from neighbours
        ArrayList<Double> newValues = new ArrayList<Double>();

        //Create loop to run sequence for subsequent lines
        for (int y = 0; y < 296; y++){

            //Create loop to run average and newValue methods for first line (note that the first value averaged is in [2][2], last is [2][297]
            for (int x = 0; x < store.image.length - 4; x++){

                // Establish size of Moore Radius = 2r+1
                // Run loop to extract first 25 values to new neighbours array
                for (int i = 0 + x; i < 5 + x; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0 + y; j < 5 + y; j++){
                        neighbours.add(store.image[i][j]);
                        //System.out.println("Normal store values " + store.image[i][j]);
                    }
                }

                //Instantiate new variable to hold total value of objects in neighbour array list
                double total = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < neighbours.size(); k++){
                    total += neighbours.get(k);
                }

                //Instantiate new variable to hold Mean Filter Moor neighbourhood value
                double neighbourhoodAverage = (total / neighbours.size());
                //System.out.println("Total = " + total);
                //System.out.println("Average = " + neighbourhoodAverage);

                //add new average value to newValues ArrayList
                newValues.add(neighbourhoodAverage);

            }
        }
        //Print to check correct number of values in row have been added to newValues ArrayList
        System.out.println("newValues ArrayList is made up of " + newValues.size() + " averaged values");

    }
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        new Analyst();
    }
}
```

Comment: You say it takes "long". Just how long is that? (Are we talking milliseconds or hours here ...?)

Comment: It takes about 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never clear the neighbours list. It will therefore contain about 25 * 300 * 300 elements when processing the last pixel of the image. That is about 90000 times more than in a correct naive implementation.

Incidentally, I don't get why you need this intermediary list at all. Why not simply do:

```
            double total = 0;
            for (int i = 0 + x; i < 5 + x; i++) {
                for (int j = 0 + y; j < 5 + y; j++){
                    total += store.image[i][j];
                    //System.out.println("Normal store values " + store.image[i][j]);
                }
            }
            double average = total / 25;
```

Comment: a succint and correct response, I'm new and struggling to spot all this stuff. I've added the line of code, it completes in a flash. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

you have 3 loops here. about 300 operations each. thats O(n^3), for 300 its about 27000000 operations!

Comment: How or where do I break it down into separate loops?

Comment: @meriton it doesnt matter, it has (1+2+3+...300) thats n(n+1)/2 which is O(n^2) for the 2 loops inside

Comment: @AndrewLyons thats more an algorithmic question, not programming